# Error 1282 if I attach a fragment shader to the program

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glew, fragment-shader

I'm trying to run a program using shaders. In [Another question I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573079/fragment-shader-inexplicable-bahaviour), I discovered that I was mixing the fixed pipeline functions with the newer stuff (from OpenGL 2.0), so I tried to remove all the "old stuff" like glMatrixMode, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. In the doubt I also removed calls like glLightfv which I'm not really sure if they're allowed if I used a programmable pipeline.

This is the main code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "utility.hpp"
#include "program.hpp"

GLfloat width=600, height=800;
Program* program_ref;

void init()
{   
    glewInit();
    Shader vertex_shader= Shader("vertex_shader",GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    // This just reads the file "vertex_shader", creates the shader and compiles it
    Shader geometry_shader= Shader(); // This means that the shader is empty
    // So the program class will be enough smart to recognize it and don't attach it
    Shader fragment_shader= Shader("fragment_shader",GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    program_ref= new Program(vertex_shader,geometry_shader,fragment_shader);
    // This creates a program, attaches the shaders to it, links and uses it
}

void display()
{
    vector<GLfloat> quad{-0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5};
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,quad.data());
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS,0,4);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glutSwapBuffers();
    cout << glGetError() << endl;
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    width=w;
    height=h;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("test");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    init();
    glewInit();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

(**Optional classes to see**, in the comments I wrote how are Program and Shader are behaving)

shader.hpp:

```
#ifndef shader_hpp
#define shader_hpp

#include "utility.hpp"
#include "shader.hpp"
#include <fstream>

#define MAX_SIZE (size_t)1.0e5


class Shader
{
private:
    GLuint id;
    GLenum type;
    bool null;
public:
    Shader()
    {
        id=-1;
        type= -1;
        null= true;
    }
    Shader(const string& filename,GLenum type)
    {
        GLchar* data= new GLchar[MAX_SIZE];
        streamsize count;
        this->type= type;
        ifstream is;
        is.open(filename);
        is.read(data,MAX_SIZE);
        count= is.gcount();
        is.close();
        id=glCreateShader(type);
        glShaderSource(id,1,(const GLchar**)&data,&count);
        glCompileShader(id);
        delete[] data;
        null= false;
    }
    GLuint getId() const
    {
        return id;
    }
    GLenum getType() const
    {
        return type;
    }
    bool isNull() const
    {
        return null;
    }
};

#endif
```

program.hpp:

```
#ifndef program_hpp
#define program_hpp

#include "utility.hpp"
#include "shader.hpp"

class Program
{
private:
    GLuint id;
public:
    Program(const Shader& vertex_shader, const Shader& geometry_shader, const Shader& fragment_shader)
    {
    id= glCreateProgram();
    if(!vertex_shader.isNull())
    {
        glAttachShader(id,vertex_shader.getId());
    }
    if(!geometry_shader.isNull())
    {
        glAttachShader(id,geometry_shader.getId());
    }
    if(!fragment_shader.isNull())
    {
        glAttachShader(id,fragment_shader.getId());
    }
    glLinkProgram(id);
    glUseProgram(id);
    }
    GLuint getId()
    {
    return id;
    }
};

#endif
```

There two classes are just made to simplify everything when using glew to compile the shaders and attach them to the program.

The problem is the following: If I just attach the vertex shader and not the fragment shader, all is fine and I see the quad drawn with the right color (red, because in the vertex shader below I'll set the color to red). If instead I also attach the fragment shader I see that the quad is white. I also tried to see what wasn't right and I printed the result of glGetError(). If I include the fragment shader I get error 1282, if I don't include it I don't get any error (0).

Vertex shader:

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position    = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_FrontColor  = vec4(1,0,0,1);
    // The only relevant thing I do is to set the color to red
    // I see the quad red if I attach only the vertex shader and not the fragment shader
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
void main()
{
    gl_fragColor= gl_Color;
}
```

Comment: You're definitely not doing it correctly; `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`, `gl_Vertex`, `gl_FrontColor`, `gl_TexCoord[]` and `gl_MultiTexCoord0` are all depricated in OpenGL 3. You need to use VBO's and uniforms. Also, what is `gl_fragColor`, I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be `gl_FragColor`.

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?

Comment: @genpfault I was missing them. I added them now and still had the error (this before reading your answer), version is 120 with OpenGL 2.0 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
{
    GLint status = GL_FALSE, len = 10;
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
    vector< char > log( len, 'X' );
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
    cerr << &log[0] << endl;
    exit( -1 );
}

GLuint LoadShader( GLenum type, const char* src )
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
    glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
    glCompileShader( shader );
    CheckStatus( shader );
    return shader;
}

GLuint LoadProgram( const char* vert, const char* geom, const char* frag )
{
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    if( vert ) glAttachShader( program, LoadShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert ) );
    if( geom ) glAttachShader( program, LoadShader( GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom ) );
    if( frag ) glAttachShader( program, LoadShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag ) );
    glLinkProgram( program );
    CheckStatus( program );
    return program;
}

#define GLSL(version, shader)  "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const GLchar* vert = GLSL
(
    120,
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position    = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
        gl_FrontColor  = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
        // The only relevant thing I do is to set the color to red
        // I see the quad red if I attach only the vertex shader and not the fragment shader
        gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    }
);

const GLchar* frag = GLSL
(
    120,
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor= gl_Color;
    }
);

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    static GLuint prog = LoadProgram( vert, NULL, frag );
    glUseProgram( prog );
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GLfloat quad[] = {-0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5};
    glVertexPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,quad);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS,0,4);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("test");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glewInit();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

As Antonie Blom pointed out `gl_fragColor` should be `gl_FragColor`.  The lower-case `f` chokes the GLSL compiler on my system.

Comment: The only problem was the 'f' instead of 'F', my bad !